# getbalance not working

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am getting this error when I type `getbalance`:

```
error: {"code":-1,"message":"std::bad_alloc"}
```

Basically, I type `getbalance` and wait for about 2 minutes and this error appears finally.

What does it mean?

Comment: Something strange about your setup is causing bitcoind to fail. Maybe your wallet is too large, maybe something is wrong with your computer, maybe something else.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means your bitcoind has not enough memory to complete the request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [rpcprotocol.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcprotocol.h#L44) the error you received is:

```
RPC_MISC_ERROR = -1, // std::exception thrown in command handling
```

In `C++`, `std::bad_alloc` is the type of object thrown as an exception by the storage allocation functions.